# How to set a conditional constraint in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I'm setting up a database for a computer store. In the database I have a table called computer_system, which has an array attribute. In the array these components go:
cpu
ram
case
mainboard
graphics card

Now to the tricky part:
The different components have their own tables and are all child tables of a table called component.
The mainboard table has an attribute called "on-board graphics". If it has a graphics card, it will be listed here. If not, the attribute is null.

Now, when I insert components in the computer_system table, I need postgres to check if the mainboard passed in, has an on_board graphics card. If not, a graphics card must be added, before the query can execute succesfully. How do I add this constraint?

I tried to explain my issue the best that I can, and I have checked all my books, but I cannot find the answer to this. Feel free to ask me, if something was unclear.
Also, here is an unfinished ER-diagram I've made for this database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAT0f.png

EDIT:
In other words what I want to do is, if mainboard.on_board_graphics is NULL, then graphics_card cannot be NULL.

Comment: Components and their characteristics change so quickly, that you'll have to redesign your schema every single day. Looks like JSON format is more suited for this, with constraints on application side.

Comment: @EgorRogov This is a school assignment, so I will not have to update the database depending on the real world's characteristics of components :)

Comment: Well, without seeing your tables it's hard to suggest something. But if you allow at most one graphics card to be attached to a motherboard, you can have FK like this: `mainboard.graphics_card_id references graphics_card(id)`. Then you can add constraint `check ((on_board_graphics is not null) or (graphics_card_id is not null))`.

Comment: @EgorRogov on_board_graphics is an attribute in another table, so I cannot access it from a CHECK constraint. But I found another way, and have answered my own question. Thanks for your feedback though!

Comment: So, the `sqlfiddle` is very stupid. Take a look at this [paste](http://pastebin.com/aG62Pww3). The problem solved with trigger.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way is to perform a CHECK constrain, which would not allow graphics_card and on_board_graphics to be null at the same time. But on_board_graphics is in another table, and since postgresql does not allow subquery's in CHECK's, this was not a solution.

I solved this by adding a function and a trigger like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION graphics_guaranteed() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
BEGIN

IF 
(SELECT on_board FROM mainboard WHERE NEW.mainboard = mainboard.name) IS NULL
AND
NEW.graphics_card IS NULL
THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'graphics not found';
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER graphics_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON computer_system
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE graphics_guaranteed();
```

Hope this helps, if some one else stumbles upon the same problem.